# Example of a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a given measurable function such that $f(x,y,u)$ satisfies
$$
C_1(u(x)-u(y))\leq f(x,y,u)\leq C_2(u(x)-u(y))
$$
for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, for some constant $C_1,C_2>0$

I can see that $f(x,y,u)=u(x)-u(y)$ itself satisfies the above hypothesis with $C_1=C_2=1$. Can someone please give some nontrivial example that satisfies the above hypothesis on $f$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $u$ a function or a real number?

Comment: Thanks for the question. u is a function. I edited it. Please see it.

Comment: What do yo mean by $f(x,y,u)$ if $u$ is a function?

Comment: Hi, $f$ is a function of $u$. That's why $f$ is written like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remark, if $u$ is a function, either you can write for example $f(x,y,u(x))$ or you should have defined $f : \mathbb R^{2n}× F(\mathbb R^{n},\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ where $F(\mathbb R^{n},\mathbb R)$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $\mathbb R$. Let take this last convention.

To have such a function $f$, you can take any function $g : \mathbb R^{2n}× F(\mathbb R^{n},\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ globally bounded by above and below (if you need explicit examples, take for example $g(x,y,u) = \sin(x)+\sin(y)\sin(u(x))$), then define
$$
f(x,y,u) = g(x,y,u)\,(u(x)-u(y))
$$

And actually, the converse is true! If $f$ is a function verifying your assumptions, then you can define
$$
g(x,y,u) = \frac{f(x,y,u)}{u(x)-u(y)}\,\mathbf 1_{\{u(x)-u(y)≠0\}}
$$
which is a bounded function of $x$, $y$ and $u$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder in such a case, if the function $f$ should be defined as $f(x,y,u(x),u(y),u(x)-u(y))$, since $u$ can take values at $y$ and if we assume $f$ is measurable in all the variables.

Comment: Basically, I am unable to make it clear what should be the domain of the function measurable function $f$ which satisfies the given condition $C_1(u(x)-u(y))\leq f(x,y,u)\leq C_2(u(x)-u(y))$ for every $x,y,\in\mathbb{R}$. From here, it seems to me the points in domain should be $(x,y,u(x),u(y),u(x)-u(y))$. Please have a look. Thanks.